# Serialize a Map<FooCategory, List<Foo>> using gson Grails view

Tags: json, grails, serialization, groovy, gson

Our backend is building a Map of `FooCategory` as key and the value is a list of `Foo` elements.  Since the controller adds this to the model for the `json` rendering process the Grails `gson` file looks like this:

```
model {
    List<String> names
    Map<FooCategory, List<Foo>> categories
}

json {
  names names
  categories <<what is the syntax>>
}
```

After multiple trials, I'm not able actually to get a valid reference to the list of Foo elements. I would like for instance to generate `json` output like this:

```
{
  "names": ["name1", "name2"],
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "category_1",
      "fooCount": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "category_5",
      "fooCount": 8
    }
  ] 
}
```

Next step will be to pass the list of `Foo` elements to a template using the `tmpl.templateName(fooElements)` syntax, but for now I'm just stalled at the count attribute. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just a heads up: JSON only allows string keys.  Depending on what a FooCategory is, this might need some thought how to represent the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that Grails' views handle Iterable entities using `tmpl` but since Map is not iterable we must explicitly call `entrySet()` method. Here a working version:

```
model {
    List<String> names
    Map<FooCategory, List<Foo>> categories
}

json {
  def stats = categories.entrySet().collect { cat ->
      [ name: cat.key.name, fooCount: cat.value.size() ]
  }

  names names
  categories stats
}
```

Now the Iterable (`categories.entrySet()`) could be passed to a template which will look like this:

```
model {
  Map.Entry<FooCategory, List<Foo>> entry
}

json {
  FooCategory fooCategory = entry.key
  List fooElements = entry.value

  ...
}
```